# Why did Proto-Slavic *dьnьsь (today) change to Serbo-Croatian "danas" instead of to *dnas?

Tags: historical-linguistics, bosnian-croatian-serbian, slovenian

By the Havlik's law, the front yer in the first syllable of *dьnьsь was weak, so why didn't it disappear?

It disappeared in most Slavic languages (like Czech "dnes" or Bulgarian "dnes"), but apparently not in Serbo-Croatian or Slovene. Why?

An obvious answer might be that the Serbo-Croatian "danas" is a borrowing from Chakavian, where the yer in the first syllable was regularly preserved. However, that doesn't explain the Slovene form "danes".

Comment: To me, a naïve not so good speaker of South Slavic with no special expertise in historical linguistics, it seems expected, **dьnь* became *dan* and the stress is on the first syllable, and unlike in East Slavic, *danas* and *noćas* are still the main words for these concepts and people subconsciously analyse them as *dan-* plus a suffix.

Comment: Cf. Slovene pekel, Serbo-Croatian pakao for Proto-Slavic *pьkъlъ (although that is a noun which may be influenced by oblique case forms)

Comment: @ain92 Serbo-Croatian phonotactics doesn't allow for a word to start with pk-.

Comment: By the way, the assertion about Bulgarian is misleading, lots of people say something more like денес or дънъс.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer _денес or дънъс_ - not really, except maybe in particular dialects (region of Macedonia?). Most Bulgarians in informal speech would simplify it to нес or (with a diminutive suffix) неска, even in places close to Serbia.

Comment: For instance see [this map](https://ibl.bas.bg//bulgarian_dialects/) and listen to the [recording from Гранитово, Белоградчишко](https://ibl.bas.bg//bulgarian_dialects/audio/29_granitovo-belogradchik.ogg) - around 2:00

Comment: the lady is saying something like "(д)неска оплевиш, един-два дена вали, и пак тръгне тревата нагоре" - "today you pull the weeds, it rains for a day or two, and the grass grows up again"